# Apache Flink: Java can't access sink2.StatefulSink

Tags: java, maven, apache-flink

When trying to build a flink job i get the following error message:

```
java: cannot access org.apache.flink.api.connector.sink2.StatefulSink
  class file for org.apache.flink.api.connector.sink2.StatefulSink not found
```

The troublesome code looks like this:

```java
KafkaSink<String> sink = KafkaSink.<String>builder()
                .setBootstrapServers(BOOTSTRAP_SERVER)
                .setRecordSerializer(KafkaRecordSerializationSchema.builder()
                        .setTopic(OUTPUT_TOPIC)
                        .setValueSerializationSchema(new SimpleStringSchema())
                        .build()
                )
                .setDeliveryGuarantee(DeliveryGuarantee.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
                .build();
```

I don't know why the class can't be found, I added the needed dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>1.16-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're using a not-released version (SNAPSHOT) instead of the latest released version (1.15.1 at the moment)?

Comment: no, and i changed it and it works